# How to combine span with paragraph to behave as a single paragraph

Tags: css, reactjs

I have RichText editor and I want to let user create its own `figcaption` for a figure. However, the number of a figure should be generated separetely. I want to combine user description of a figure (`p` tag) with a number (`span` tag) to make them behave as a single `paragraph`. I tried with `float: left` on a `span` but I can't center it properly (the combined `figcaption` should have the width of entire page instead of fitting the width of an image.

Here is my demo: https://codepen.io/degel123/pen/rNRpWNQ

As you can see, this `float` element does not center properly. I tried adding

```
  width: fit-content;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
```

to `figcaption` style but then content is splitted into two lines instead of keeping it in single one.

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: flex` for the figcaption, and then apply `justify-content`;

```js
figcaption {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

p {
  margin: 0
}
```

Comment: Hi, but if the paragraph is longer than single line, then it does not look good. Here is my demo with float left but I can''t figure out how to align this `span` element to `p` instead of having it on the very `left` side: https://codepen.io/degel123/pen/vYPpdVm

Answer (score 0):

Just use display flex and justify the content center to make it horizontally centered and then align the items center to make it vertically centered and then a .5 rem gap to show it clean (my choice)
Here is a demo

```css
p {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  max-width: 15rem;
}


span {
  float: left;
}

figcaption {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  gap:.5rem;
  text-align: center;
}

div {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <figure>
    <div style="width: 200px">
    <img width="100%" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/emoji-datasource-apple/img/apple/64/1f601.png"/>
    </div>
    <figcaption>
    <span>Fig 2.1. </span><p>Someeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee descriptionsssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss... </p>
    </figcaption>
    </figure>
</body>
</html>
```

I just updated the snipped that you gave and made changes in the CSS of figcaption

Edit - I addded display flex and justify content center in the p tag as well and in figcaption added flex-direction as column so now they will be stacked vertically so no matter what the length of the description is it won't look bad, and also because now p tag i centered it wont be looking ugly

Comment: Hi, but if the paragraph is longer than single line, then it does not look good. Here is my demo with float left but I can''t figure out how to align this `span` element to `p` instead of having it on the very `left` side: https://codepen.io/degel123/pen/vYPpdVm

Comment: I updated the snipped check it out, it addresses the problem of long text